# How to glow label text using Jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to use code given at http://jsfiddle.net/Jf4vB/211/. The code runs perfectly in fiddle but when I trying to excute same code in my projuect I am not getting that "Glow Effect"

My code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeColor(id) {
        nIntervId = setInterval("flashText('"+id+"')", 1000);
    }
$.fn.glowEffect = function (start, end, duration, callback) {

        if (this.data("last-glow"))
            start = this.data("last-glow");
        return this.animate(
            {
                'placeholder': end
            },
            {
                duration: duration,
                step: function (now, fx) {
                    now = parseInt(start + (start - end) * (fx.pos));
                    $(fx.elem).css("text-shadow", "0px 0px" + now + "px #c61a1a").data("last-glow", now);
                },
                complete: callback
            });
    };
function flashText(id) {        
var oElem = $('#'+id).find(":checkbox").next();
        oElem.stop()      .glowEffect(0, 50, 1000,
            function () {
                $(this).glowEffect(50, 0, 1000);
            });
    }
function stopTextColor() {
        clearInterval(nIntervId);
    }    
</script>
<div id="divchkBox">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox" runat="server" Text="hi" />
</div>
<asp:Button ID="start" Text="start" runat="server" OnClientClick="changeColor('divchkBox');" />
<asp:Button ID="stop" Text="stop" runat="server" OnClientClick="stopTextColor();" />
```

all I am trying achieve is, on click of start button -> text next to checkbox("Hi") should have the effect as in above fiddle continuously till I click on stop button.

Comment: var oElem = $('#'+id).find(":checkbox").next();
checkout for this line I think here id = chkBox but I think it should be divchkBox , as you are the checkbox id and going for its descendent's search.

Comment: Any hints from the console? - F12

Comment: @myk. id is properly going. I edited my question to pass the divcheckbox. Can you please double check my code? I am getting correct innerHTML or label content("Hi") when I am expanding oElem.

Comment: @techfoobar what kind of hint of I am looking for? I am new to using F12 console and it is blank when I am running my code.

Comment: The console can give you important hints regarding why JS code doesn't work as expected. but in your case, since its empty you're out of luck using the console.

Comment: install firebug in you browser and run the application and check the console what status it is showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own mistake. It was IE9's compatible view which was preventing proper running of code. The code excuted correctly in chrome and guided me in correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

Did you missed open script tag before the scripts?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
// this one
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeColor(id) {...}
</script>
```

Comment: no. I have that in my code. I forgot to copy this line here in question. Thanks for pointing it out. I inserted it in question.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code

```
 <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <style>
        .divchkBox
        {
            font-size: 50px;
            color: #c61a1a;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var divchkBox = $(".divchkBox");
            var v = $('#<%=start1.ClientID %>'); //$('#start');


            $.fn.glowEffect = function(start, end, duration, callback) {

                if (this.data("last-glow"))
                    start = this.data("last-glow");

                return this.animate({
                    'placeholder': end
                }, {
                    duration: duration,
                    step: function(now, fx) {
                        now = parseInt(start + (end - start) * (fx.pos));
                        $(fx.elem).css("text-shadow", "0px 0px " + now + "px #c61a1a")
                .data("last-glow", now);
                    },
                    complete: callback
                });

            };

            v.click(function() {

                divchkBox
        .stop()
        .glowEffect(0, 50, 1000,
                    function() {
                        $(this).glowEffect(50, 0, 1000);
                    });
                return false;
            });

            e.click(function() {
                alert('e');
                divchkBox
        .stop()
        .glowEffect(0, 50, 1000,
                    function() {
                        $(this).glowEffect(50, 0, 1000);
                    });
            });


        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div class="divchkBox">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox" runat="server" Text="hi asdfasdf asdfas dfasdf" />
    </div>

    <asp:Button ID="start1" Text="start" runat="server"   />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is "e"?even if i comment out that code...its not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<style type="text/css">
  .red
  {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #c61a1a;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>


<div id="divchkBox">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox" runat="server" Text="hi" CssClass="red" />
</div>
<asp:Button ID="start" Text="start" runat="server" 
     OnClientClick="return changeColor('chkBox');" />
<asp:Button ID="stop" Text="stop" runat="server" 
     OnClientClick="return stopTextColor();" />



<script type="text/javascript">

function changeColor(id) {
  nIntervId = setInterval("flashText('" + id + "')", 1000);
  return false;
}
$.fn.glowEffect = function (start, end, duration, callback) {

   if (this.data("last-glow"))
     start = this.data("last-glow");

   return this.animate(
   {
      'placeholder': end
   }, {
      duration: duration,
      step: function (now, fx) {
         now = parseInt(start + (end - start) * (fx.pos));
         $(fx.elem).css("text-shadow", "0px 0px " + now + "px #c61a1a")
         .data("last-glow", now);
      },
      complete: callback
     });

};

function flashText(id) {
 var oElem = $('#' + id).next();
 oElem.stop().glowEffect(0, 50, 1000,
               function () {
                    $(this).glowEffect(50, 0, 1000);
                });
}

function stopTextColor() {
  clearInterval(nIntervId);
  return false;
}

</script>
```